# How do I put an image in my answer?

Tags: support

I would like to put a plot in my answer such as in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6907/an-adaptation-of-the-kullback-leibler-distance) but I don't know how.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the icons above the answer window where you enter text there is an icon that allows you to upload an image from either a url or a local drive.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @andy - always something small that is missed!

Answer (score 2):

As @Andy said, it is much simpler to use the embedded editor, as it will, for example, automatically manage the list of hyperlinks and allow you to upload an image directly from your computer.

Technically, images are hosted on [imgur](http://imgur.com/), after they have been loaded from your computer (the base address will be `https://i.stack.imgur.com/`). In case you already have images on this web-sharing system, giving the URL works just fine.

In Markdown syntax, embedding an image is as simple as

```
![RLogo](http://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg)
```

or

```
![RLogo][1]

[1]: http://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg
```

which produces

[image: RLogo]

So, this is basically the same idea as for a simple hyperlink, which when written as `[Here is the R logo](http://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg)` actually reads [Here is the R logo](http://www.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg). We just need to prefix the hyperlink with a single `!`. The rest of the syntax is pure Markdown.